# How to create Spatial Reference System in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, polygon, postgis-2.0, line

I have some Attribute and the coordinate and the coordinate reference system. I want to create a DBmanagamet form my spatial data. To do that I want to create one table with name Spa_ref_sys, but I don't know how to populate my table. The point of this is that I want to connect my spatial data with QGIS.  How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a PostGIS database using

```
create extension postgis
```

the  "spatial_ref_sys" table is created automatically. I don't see any use case where you would want to do that by hand.

---

If you are new to the technology, you really need to read some basic literature. Just asking about random details here won't get you anywhere. See for example [Getting started with PostGIS](http://www.bostongis.com/?content_name=postgis_tut01).

Comment: In fact I am a beginner in "DBmanagement spatial" and I need some help. Please, can you explain with more details that?
Thanks!